# Overhead for "rich type" struct in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, struct, compile-time, overhead

I'd like keep track of what is essentially "type" information at compile time for a few functions which currently take arguments of the same type.  Here's an example; Say I have two functions `getThingIndex(uint64_t t)` and `getThingAtIndex(uint64_t tidx)`.  The first function treats the argument as an encoding of the `thing`, does a non-trivial computation of an index, and returns it.  One can then get the actual "thing" by calling `getThingAtIndex`. `getThingAtIndex`, on the other hand, assumes you're querying the structure and already have an index.  The latter of the two methods is faster, but, more importantly, I want to avoid the headaches that might result from passing a `thing` to `getThingAtIndex` or by passing an `index` to `getThingIndex`.

I was thinking about creating types for `thing` and thing index sort of like so:

```cpp
struct Thing { uint64_t thing; }
struct ThingIndex { uint64_t idx; }
```

And then changing the signatures of the functions above to be

```cpp
getThingIndex(Thing t)
getThingAtIndex(ThingIndex idx)
```

Now, despite the fact that `Thing` and `ThingIndex` encode the same
underlying type, they are nonetheless distinct at compile time and I 
have less opportunity to make stupid mistakes by passing an index to
`getThingIndex` or a thing to `getThingAtIndex`.

However, I'm concerned about the overhead of this approach.  The functions
are called many (10s-100s of millions of) times, and I'm curious if the 
compiler will optimize away the creation of these structures which essentially
do nothing but encode compile-time type information.  If the compiler won't 
perform such an optimization, is there a way to create these types of "rich types"
with zero overhead?

Comment: `sizeof(Thing) == sizeof(uint64_t)`, whats the issue here?

Comment: I might be missing something, but if you are passing in the Thing to find, then computing the index of the matching Thing and then returning the matching Thing, wouldn't you just have the Thing? I don't know your design or constraints, etc, but seems like this might be better suited to using a `std::` collection with a strongly typed `Thing`, maybe a `std::set<Thing>` or something like that.

Comment: Well, you would be passing these parameters in by value, so the compiler should allocate stack space for the struct.  Not sure how much overhead there is if the structs is the same size a a unit64_t.  I would compile some code with various permutations, and look at the generated assembly listing to see what the compiler is doing.  Run some timing benchmarks also.

Comment: @millsj, I know that the size is the same; my question is about runtime overhead (i.e. will the compiler optimize away the construction of the containing struct).

Comment: @pstrjds The constraint is that initially I have to deal with "Things", that I'm reading in from a file.  However, I've built a minimal perfect hash so that I can assign each "Thing" to an index.  So, after initially calculating the index of each Thing, I want to deal strictly with the indices to avoid the repeated lookup overhead.

Comment: Okay, from your question it did not appear that you ever got the index back, it sounded like you got the Thing back.

Comment: @pstrjds, You're right. I've updated the question to more correctly reflect the actual constraints; thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the disassembly.

```
unsigned long long * x = new unsigned long long;
0110784E  push        8  
01107850  call        operator new (01102E51h)  
01107855  add         esp,4  
01107858  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0D4h],eax  
0110785E  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0D4h]  
01107864  mov         dword ptr [x],eax  
*x = 5;
01107867  mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
0110786A  mov         dword ptr [eax],5  
01107870  mov         dword ptr [eax+4],0
```

And the struct.

```
struct Thing { unsigned long long a; };
Thing * thing = new Thing;
0133784E  push        8  
01337850  call        operator new (01332E51h)  
01337855  add         esp,4  
01337858  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0D4h],eax  
0133785E  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0D4h]  
01337864  mov         dword ptr [thing],eax  
thing->a = 5;
01337867  mov         eax,dword ptr [thing]  
0133786A  mov         dword ptr [eax],5  
01337870  mov         dword ptr [eax+4],0
```

There is no difference in the two instructions. The compiler doesn't care that `this->a` is a member of the struct, it accesses it as if you just declared `unsigned long long a`.

Comment: I see.  Out of curiosity, how did you get such a nice looking disassembly?  I'd like to try the same experiment except with the variables being stack allocated rather than heap allocated.

Comment: I generated the disassembly using Visual Studio. When debugging, you can select `Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly`